# Parameter 'initialState' cannot be referenced in its initializer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

In my ReactJS / Typescript app, I'm getting the following error in my store.ts:

> Parameter 'initialState' cannot be referenced in its initializer.

```
interface IinitialState {
  fiatPrices: [];
  wallets: [];
  defaultCurrency: string;
}

const initialState = {
  fiatPrices: [],
  wallets: [],
  defaultCurrency: ''
}
```

...

```
export function initializeStore (initialState:IinitialState = initialState) {
  return createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
  )
}
```

Anyone else run into this issue? Currently having to rely on `// @ts-ignore`

---

Entire store.ts file:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

interface IinitialState {
  fiatPrices: [];
  wallets: [];
  defaultCurrency: string;
}

const initialState = {
  fiatPrices: [],
  wallets: [],
  defaultCurrency: ''
}

export const actionTypes = {
  GET_PRICES: 'GET_PRICES'
}

// REDUCERS
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_PRICES:
      return state
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// MOCK API
export async function getProgress(dispatch: any) {
  try {
    const priceList = await fetchPrices();
    return dispatch({ type: actionTypes.GET_PRICES, payload: priceList })
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  }
}

// Wait 1 sec before resolving promise
function fetchPrices() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ progress: 100 });
      }, 1000);
  });
}

// ACTIONS
export const addLoader = () => (dispatch: any) => {
  getProgress(dispatch);
}

// @ts-ignore
export function initializeStore (initialState:IinitialState = initialState) {
  return createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
  )
}
```

---

withReduxStore lib file

```
import React from 'react'
import { initializeStore, IinitialState } from '../store'

const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'
const __NEXT_REDUX_STORE__ = '__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__'

function getOrCreateStore (initialState: IinitialState) {
  // Always make a new store if server, otherwise state is shared between requests
  if (isServer) {
    return initializeStore(initialState)
  }

  // Create store if unavailable on the client and set it on the window object
  // Waiting for (@ts-ignore-file) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19573 to be implemented
  // @ts-ignore
  if (!window[__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__]) {
    // @ts-ignore
    window[__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__] = initializeStore(initialState)
  }
  // @ts-ignore
  return window[__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__]
}

// @ts-ignore
export default App => {
  return class AppWithRedux extends React.Component {
    // @ts-ignore
    static async getInitialProps (appContext) {
      // Get or Create the store with `undefined` as initialState
      // This allows you to set a custom default initialState
      const reduxStore = getOrCreateStore()

      // Provide the store to getInitialProps of pages
      appContext.ctx.reduxStore = reduxStore

      let appProps = {}
      if (typeof App.getInitialProps === 'function') {
        appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)
      }

      return {
        ...appProps,
        initialReduxState: reduxStore.getState()
      }
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    constructor (props) {
      super(props)
      this.reduxStore = getOrCreateStore(props.initialReduxState)
    }

    render () {
      return <App {...this.props} reduxStore={this.reduxStore} />
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code where `reducer` ist set? I guess you have to initialize the state in the reducer method

Comment: @messerbill just added entire store.ts file reducer is currently inside it, but will move out eventually, along with actions.

Comment: try just to change `export function initializeStore (initialState:IinitialState = initialState) {` to `export function initializeStore () {`

Comment: @messerbill oh yeah so that works without error... I'll test in a bit.

Comment: Oh problem, my withReduxStore file requires an argument... posting in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function initializeStore (initialState:IinitialState = initialState) { ... }
```

is not valid by any means, not just in TypeScript. It's incorrect to suppress the error with `@ts-ignore`.

`initialState` parameter shadows the variable of the same name from enclosing scope, so default parameter value refers the parameter itself. This will result in discarding default parameter value with ES5 target and in an error with ES6 target.

The parameter and default value should have different names:

```
function initializeStore (initialState:IinitialState = defaultInitialState) { ... }
```

Notice that the use of `defaultInitialState` isn't needed in a reducer, due to how [initial state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state) works. Initial state from `createStore` takes precedence if `combineReducers` is not in use.

Comment: Yeah I was shadowing it, but I'm still getting a type missmatch error after renaming initialState defaultInitialState. I may have to post another question. I still had to resort to using `any`.

Comment: I'm quite sure the case is simple and the question will be shortly answered. Consider pinging me if you will have problems with solving it.

Comment: Actually, not sure what happened, but the TypeScript errors went away, again thanks for your help!